# How to disable the searching for binaries

Tags: eclipse-cdt

Is there a setting for the `CDT plugin` ( version `9.4.3`) to disable the `Searching for binaries...` job?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In `Project Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings`, in the `Binary Parsers` tab, uncheck all entries. That should disable the `Searching for binaries...` job.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, do you also know how to achieve that programatically?

Comment: @JohnDoe: By programmatically, do you mean using the Eclipse plugin API?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm thinking of, because I want this setting by default and I will use a plugin to configure it

Comment: @JohnDoe: Looking at the [source code](https://git.eclipse.org/c/cdt/org.eclipse.cdt.git/tree/core/org.eclipse.cdt.ui/src/org/eclipse/cdt/ui/newui/BinaryParsTab.java?id=4c50b40f53125c49ba0567738084808f311ea4c6#n420) of that preference page, you probably want to call something like `CoreModelUtil.setBinaryParserIds(configs, ids)` with an empty list of binary parser ids. The configs can be obtained with something like `CoreModel.getProjectDescription(...).getConfigurations()`.